# Radius of Convergence and Expectation of a Power Series

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, power-series

I'm looking at a proof, and am unsure how they get to the conclusion at the end (this is from Wainwright’s High Dim. Book).

> Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$ s.t. for non-negative values $(\nu, \alpha)$
>
> $$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda(X - \mu)}\right] \leq e^{\frac{\nu^2 \lambda^2}{2}}, \quad\forall |\lambda| < \frac{1}{\alpha}.$$
>
> Then for some number $c > 0$ we have that $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] < \infty$ for all $|\lambda| < c$. This is equivalent to saying that $\sup_{k \geq 2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k} < \infty$.

Expanding the series and taking the expectation inside the sum (assume we can do this as I don't want to state all the details as to why) we get
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda X}\right] = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^k\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!} < \infty.$$
They state that $\sup_{k \geq 2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k} < \infty$.

**Question.** How do they arrive at this radius of convergence explicitly? Using the definition I get only that

$$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k} \leq \sup_{k \geq 2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k},$$

where, $\limsup_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k} < \infty,$ doesn't necessarily imply that, $\sup_{k \geq 2}\left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^k}{k!}\right)^{1/k} < \infty$?

Comment: If $X$ is the  zero random variable then the radius of convergence is obviously $\infty$.

Comment: They are saying that the radius of convergence is greater than $0$, not that it is finite.

Comment: There are multiple mistakes in your statement. If $X$ is a positive  random variable with infinite expectation and $\lambda =-1$ then the moments are not even defined. I thing the hypothesis should be $Ee^{\lambda |X|} <\infty$ fro some $\lambda >0$.

Comment: Added more necessary details. I believe the hypothesis should be equivalent to what you have now.

Comment: The radius of convegence of $\sum a_nx^{n}$ is the **reciprocal** of $\lim \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$.

Comment: I see... they must of misquoted (edited this). The reciprocal gives that $\sup(\cdot) \leq \limsup(\cdot)$. If $\limsup = \infty$, why can we not have $\sup = \infty$ though, i.e. it seems we need strict inequality $\sup(\cdot) < \limsup(\cdot)$?

Comment: I have proved that in my answer. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I think I follow now: Since the series converges, we have $\sum_{k=2} \lambda^kEX^k/k! < \infty \Rightarrow \lambda^kEX^k/k! < \infty$ for all $k \geq 2$, which in turn implies that $\sup_{k\geq 2} (\cdot)^{1/k} < \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0<a<c$ then $Ee^{a|X|}\leq Ee^{aX}+Ee^{-aX} <\infty$. Since $e^{a|X|} \geq \frac {a^{n}|X|^{n}} {n!}$ for each $n$ we get $(\frac {a^{n}E|X|^{n}} {n!})^{1/n} \leq (Ee^{a|X|})^{1/n}$. Hence the series $\sum \lambda^{k}EX^{k} /k!$ converges for $|\lambda| <a$.

[The radius of convergence $R$ is $>0$. It need not be finite].

Answer (score 1):

For any real sequence, the following are equivalent
$$
(a)\, \lim\sup a_k<\infty\quad\textrm{and}\quad \, (b)\, \sup_k a_k<\infty
$$
Indeed, $\lim\sup a_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sup_{k\ge n}a_k)$. If $(a)$ holds, $\sup_{k\ge n}a_k<\infty$ for all $n$, in particular for $n=1$. If $(b)$ holds, since the sequence $b_n=\sup_{k\ge n}a_k$ is non-increasing and bounded above thanks to $(b)$, it converges to some finite $\lim\sup a_k$.